# error in ionic capacitor when add ios: symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.bundle

Tags: ios, macos, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm new in ios. (I'm using macmini with M1 chip).

I build an ionic project (with capacitor) on windows and create the android app without any error.

But when I switch to mac, and run the command `npx cap add ios` I have an error `symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.bundle`.

The following is the result of run the command `npx cap add ios` :

```
% npx cap add ios
ℹ Installing iOS dependencies – Skipping: already installed
✔ Adding native xcode project in: /Users/username/Documents/AppName/ios in 15.44ms
✔ add in 16.67ms
✔ Copying web assets from www to ios/App/public in 248.71ms
✔ Copying native bridge in 3.05ms
✔ Copying capacitor.config.json in 2.60ms
✔ copy in 262.60ms
✔ Updating iOS plugins in 3.08ms
  Found 0 Capacitor plugins for ios:
✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod install" (may take several minutes): 
✖ update ios: 
[error] /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require': dlsym(0x7fd7c441b9b0, Init_bigdecimal): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.bundle (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Users/anastamimi/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Users/anastamimi/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link helped me at a similar problem (LoadError - dlsym(0x7fe291e235f0, Init_ffi_c): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle):

See solution at the bottom in https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3897

Right-click on *Terminal* in Finder
Get Info
Open with Rosetta

sudo gem install ffi     (ffi was the missing component in my case)